# Backbone sync request sequence

Tags: rest, backbone.js

I've got a Backbone web application that talks to a RESTful PHP server. For PUT and POST it matters in which order the requests arrive at the server and for GET it matters in which order the responses arrive at the client.

The web application does not need to be used concurrently by multiple users, but what might happen is that the user changes its name twice really fast. Then the order in which the server processes `PUT /name/Ann` and `PUT /name/Bea` determines whether the name is set to Ann or Bea.

[Backbone.Safesync](https://github.com/amccloud/backbone-safesync/blob/master/backbone-safesync.js) and [Backbone.Sync.AjaxQueue](https://github.com/jbutz/Backbone.Sync.AjaxQueue) are two libraries that try to solve this problem. Doesn't Safesync only solve the problem with GET? Sync.AjaxQueue is outdated, but might serve as inspiration to implement a custom queued sync function. Making sync synchronous would solve the problem. If a request is only sent after the previous response is received, then only one request is processed at a time.

Any advice on how to proceed?

BTW: I don't think using PATCH requests would solve anything, because in my example the same attribute is changed twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to solve this, here's two:

1. add a timestamp to all requests, store it in the DB as "modified" and let the server check whether the timestamp of the new request is later than the one in the DB in order to be valid
2. use Promises to delay the second request from being made before the first one is responded on, there's [a promise/deferred mechanism built into jquery](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), but you can also use a 3rd party one, for instance [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or [when](https://github.com/cujojs/when)

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford the delay, an easy approach is to set the `async` option to `false` when you call whatever method you're calling that results in the Backbone.sync. For example, in the appropriate model(s) simply override the default `sync` method to include the additional option.